# Seeking GeoServer tutorials?

Tags: geoserver, references

What are sources where I can learn how to use GeoServer?

I know of these two sites:

- http://geoserver.org/ - which in fact is not working (at least at the moment)
- http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoserver-intro/ - not only (tutorials) for GeoServer

But I am interested in more complex information, and not to read only documentation.

Answer (score 7):

I have some notes and tutorials on setting GeoServer up and building web mapping apps at http://ian01.geog.psu.edu.

Comment: has this site gone away? Do you have an alternative site with the goodies? Cheers

Comment: It lives in the US so I may have problems rebooting this week

Comment: The Cleaner probably unplugged it to vacuum the floor .. Cheers ..

Comment: The link here seems to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is a 'quickstart' and may not qualify as more complex information, I found this quite thorough and useful, it uses the geoserver installation on the osgeolive image/bootable disk. I use the virtual machine with the free VMware Player:

http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/geoserver_quickstart.html

Answer (score 4):

I found this is also a good one: https://khayer.wordpress.com/category/gis/openlayer/, which talks about how to integrate Openlayers with Geoserver

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn with video and example , here is the nice link to learn.
Here it has been shown that how to publish shape files(point,line and polygon) to geoserver.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiH4K1NLOZA

Answer (score 1):

Books on [packtpub.com](https://www.packtpub.com):

1. GeoServer Beginner’s Guide
   [https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/geoserver-beginner's-guide](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/geoserver-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide)
2. GeoServer Cookbook
   https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/geoserver-cookbook
3. Mastering GeoServer
   https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/mastering-geoserver