# Adding .bil raster file to GeoServer and viewing it on GeoServer or GeoNode

Tags: raster, geoserver

Ok so my Boss gave me this job. Uptil now i was working on ESRI products and this is my first venture into OpenGEO.

He has given me a link, http://www.worldclim.org/current, from where i need to use the 10 arc minute Bioclim raster which are in .bil format and add them to GeoServer. I am absolutely clueless how to do that?

Pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check out [GDAL](http://gdal.org) to convert the .bil files to GeoTiffs that GeoServer can display efficiently. I would look at [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).

Comment: no i don't need to code, i just need to import it in this format itself

Comment: one more info, i did find that to "store" the raster data i had to put it in Ehrd format, which accepted the file. But to publish the layer, the raster has generic cartesian 2D co-ordinate system (Native SRS) and it is asking for Declared SRS. I did try to put it in some arbitrary co-ordinate system but then i m not able to view the image, only the map controls are visible.

Comment: You should probably pick epsg:4326 as a random SRS :-)

Comment: i did that but unfortunately when i click preview layers and select OpenLayers, i am not able to view the image

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to GeoServer, the responses to an earlier [GeoServer Tutorials](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7987/tutorials-for-geoserver) question may be a good place to start.

Comment: i have gone through the tutorials, but no tutorials guide you about raster datas other than GeoTIFF

Comment: Sounds like the questions are really: How can I convert BIL to GeoTIFF using opensource software? and/or How do I serve a BIL image file from GeoServer?  I've not done either of these things so will leave to others to provide further response.

Comment: No i do not need to convert to GeoTIFF. I wish to add the raster as it is and view it by usling the Preview Layer functionality of GeoServer

Comment: Hardly anyone supports bil format rasters and GeoServer doesn't so converting is the way to go. Welcome to GIS :-)

Comment: :D oh k. i never really dealt with raster data before. most of my gis developement has been with digitized vector dataset. you did give me the GDAL but how do i convert it to GeoTIFF directly? is GDAL a software?

Comment: ok think i got it, i converted the .bil file to .tiff using ArcGIS 10 now to try and upload it into the geoserver

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks iant for guiding me to convert .bil format to Tiff. I was able to do that using ArcGIS 10 (though it can also be done using ERDAS Imagine). After that imported the layer and published it and set the SRS to epsg:4326 as you suggested. It is working thanks